# how Derby database works?

Tags: java, database, derby

Wikipedia states that derby database can be embedded in a java application. Does it mean that we do not need to install a database server separately as if we were using Mysql for the same application?

Does it mean that we can simply ship a jar file with the database embedded in it, and not worry about installing a database server separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, Derby is a database internally supported by Java. This database can be of particular use when creating desktop applications or creating applications in which we do not want to install a database server on target machine.

Derby libraries can directly read database files that are held in JAR archives, so no need to install Database servers for this. Derby has all of the features that you would expect from a modern SQL database.

Comment: The link you provided requires some authentication. anyway does it mean that the database server automatically starts when we start the application? and quits when we quit the application?

Comment: whole point is, when you access the Derby DB from inside a Java application, Derby Engine starts running inside JVM and becomes part of your application , you can stop it from your application as well.whole point is when you call the DB it starts and you can shut it down when you need to

Comment: @DesirePRG does that answer your question?

Comment: There's lots of information about packaging and deploying Derby embedded applications in the Derby docs, for example http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/cgsintdo.html